# MEX (C -> Matlab) converting to int -> double different on mac/linux and windows

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I have a Matlab script that calls a C code which reads my dat file consisting of all my data which of one is the timestamp_low. Running my script on windows I get the correct time value of 4.1472*10^9 but of linux/mac I get the value 1.8447*10^19. Essentially I'm only reading from the file and saving it.

```
unsigned int timestamp_low = inBytes[0] + (inBytes[1] << 8) +
    (inBytes[2] << 16) + (inBytes[3] << 24);
mxSetField(outCell, 0, "timestamp_low", mxCreateDoubleScalar((double)timestamp_low));
```

Does anyone know if the mex-compiler works differently on different OS for this kind of stuff? I haven't written this code myself, so I'm not super familiar with details. I use it to gather CSI from a WiFi device. I've tried on different Matlab versions and on Mac/Linux and they produce the same (wrong) value.

Comment: Check the value of `timestamp_low` before you convert it to `double` - it looks like you have some UB in the expression where you convert `inBytes` to an `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have some Undefined Behaviour here:

```
unsigned int timestamp_low = inBytes[0] + (inBytes[1] << 8) +
                            (inBytes[2] << 16) + (inBytes[3] << 24);
```

(although it's not clear as you haven't told us the type of `inBytes`).

Try:

```
unsigned int timestamp_low = (unsigned int)inBytes[0] + ((unsigned int)inBytes[1] << 8) + 
                            ((unsigned int)inBytes[2] << 16) + ((unsigned int)inBytes[3] << 24);
```

Comment: Turns out if i updated xcode and recompiled the file, it worked. Still don't know why, but it works. Thanks for the quick answer though @Paul R !